# How to update a file in site-packages on Heroku

Tags: django, git, heroku

I just installed [django-robots-txt](https://github.com/nkuttler/django-robots-txt) for my django project. Now as the project states I have to edit the robot.txt file according to my needs. Since I cannot git push that file onto my Heroku Server, I am not sure how to edit this file on the server. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: What is the problem with pushing that file?

Comment: @michas Since I used pip install, the installed app is not a part of my application exactly. its a part of the requirement.txt that heroku uses to install all the supplementary resources. thats why I cannot use git add

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file on your local machine.

Do a

```
git add -u
```

to update the resources on your project.
Then

```
git commit -m "changes that you made"
```

and a

```
git push heroku master(assuming you are working on the master branch)
```

That should push your most recent changes(including the ones to robots.txt) to heroku.

Comment: Since I used pip install, the installed app is not a part of my application exactly. its a part of the requirement.txt that heroku uses to install all the supplementary resources. thats why I cannot use git add

Comment: are you using a virtualenv?

Comment: Yes I am using a virtualenv